# When calling this function in Swift 4 or later, you must pass a '()' tuple; did you mean for the input type to be '()'?

Tags: swift, swift4

I need help with its code  Why appears after of change Swift 3 for Swift 4? 
89/5000
I am moving for IOS 11 since I was with 8 I altered all the tuples of the methods
Please helpme

```
let action: () -> Void = { [unowned self] in
    self.cameraController.takePicture { self.isTakingPicture = false }}


fileprivate func takePicture() {
        guard isBelowImageLimit() && !isTakingPicture else { return }
        isTakingPicture = true
        bottomContainer.pickerButton.isEnabled = false
        bottomContainer.stackView.startLoader()
        let action: () -> Void = { [unowned self] in
          self.cameraController.takePicture { self.isTakingPicture = false }
        }

        if configuration.collapseCollectionViewWhileShot {
          collapseGalleryView(action)
        } else {
          action()
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: let action: () -> Void = { [unowned self] in
    self.cameraController.takePicture { self.isTakingPicture = false }}

Comment: You're calling `takePicture` like an async method (with a completion), and `takePicture` doesn't have such argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the code lines

```
self.cameraController.takePicture { self.isTakingPicture = false }}
```

takePicture is expecting a completion block, which takePicture doesn't have.

You can write the method:

```
fileprivate func takePicture(completion: () -> Void) {
     guard isBelowImageLimit() && !isTakingPicture else { 
       return }
     isTakingPicture = true
     bottomContainer.pickerButton.isEnabled = false
     bottomContainer.stackView.startLoader()
     let action: () -> Void = { [unowned self] in
       self.cameraController.takePicture { self.isTakingPicture = false 
     }
     }

     if configuration.collapseCollectionViewWhileShot {
      collapseGalleryView(action)
     } else {
      action()
     }
   }
  //Need to call the completion block
  completion()
}
```

Completion block needs to be called even inside guard block, may be with some boolean parameter, otherwise  "self.isTakingPicture = false" line will not get executed.